# Custom url rewrite in wordpress gives me 404 error in Google search console

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I am having a problem with my htaccess code in wordpress.

I have the following lines in htaccess :

```
RewriteRule    ^chainetv/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /wp-content/themes/all/chaine.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Process chaines
RewriteRule    ^annee/([0-9]+)/?$    /wp-content/themes/all/annee.php?year=$1    [NC,L]    # Process annees
```

The rewrite rule works fine when i am browsing my website and I can access urls like example.com/chainetv/fox/ but the problem occurs with Googlebot as it gives me 404 errors in search console. I tried to index like google but i have the not found error.

What have I missed? It works fine with me and with my website's visitors but not with Google. I need your help.

Thanks.

Comment: As you can access the urls correctly from your browser, then the same urls is accessible from any end, same .htaccess file. Something is missing.

Comment: I know but googlebot gives me 404 error. Maybe something is triggeref by wordpress?